# gocql bind not working in the case of concurrent calls

Tags: go, gocql

I have been trying to reuse a the prepared query in concurrent calls.

```
type product struct {
    query *gocql.Query
}

type resp struct {
    Pk  string
    Product Product
    Err     error
}

func (p *product) A() {
...
    respFromDB := make(chan resp, len(pks))

    for _, pk := range pks {
        go p.getAll(pk, resp)
    }

}


func (p *product) getAll(pk string, product chan resp) {
    var (
        err      error
        prodResp resp
    )

    prod := Product{}
    prodResp = resp{
        Pk: pk,
    }

    err = p.preparedStatement.Bind(gtin13).Scan(&prod.Pk,...)
    if err != nil {
        prodResp.Err = err
        product <- prodResp

        return
    }

    prodResp.Product = prod
    product <- prodResp

}
```

The pks are being passed to getAll function but the Bind function seems to not be bind every pk to the corresponding call.

Instead the some pk is being repeatedly binded.

Is there something wrong in this approach? Not sure why the pks are being binded to the corresponding calls.

The Query is created once in the main and injected for all further calls.

Comment: What type is p.preparedStatement? As far as I'm aware, a `Query` isn't necessarily safe to be used concurrently, which could be causing your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is of type Query.